# Error starting ApplicationContext in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-bean

I am trying with simple spring boot application. I am facing problem on starting an application on ApplicationContext.

> 2017-04-26 11:17:31.101  WARN 14528 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource 
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
>   2017-04-26 11:17:31.116  INFO 14528 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2017-04-26 11:17:31.121 ERROR 14528 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

I got above errors while starting an application. I am using spring boot 1.5.1.RELEASE version.

Kindly do needful.

**EDIT 1**
[image]

**EDIT 2**

```
package com.hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class, args);
}

}
```

Comment: Have you read the exception? `Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath` looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: Yes. Facing this exception.

Comment: Read the message, it gives the solution... It cannot get more clear then that.

Comment: Hibernate-validator and validation-api jars are added in classpath. It shows same error.

Comment: Not according the server that is starting it...

Comment: Do I need to exclude hibernate-validator jar ?

Comment: No you need to make sure your dependencies are correctly there and for some reason your deployment thinks it isn't there (although it is a warning and not an error) so there might be something else that is blocking your deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by excluding hibernate-validator dependency in pom.xml. It is working fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Jackson libraries not available for this boot project.
Either add Jackson libraries manually or add the following dependencies which will internally import Jackson libraries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>helloWorld</name>
    <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <dozer.version>5.4.0</dozer.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I added jackson-core, jackson-annotations, jackson-databind dependencies in pom.xml but still it shows same error.

Comment: Hi Kumaresh, Please create sample boot project using https://start.spring.io/   It will add all required jar automatically. Hope it can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding the below dependency for Jackson:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

Also make sure to remove classpath entries for Jackson